# How to validate a unique field on both the primary table and the foreign table based on a column on the primary table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have the following problem: I have a product table that has a cod column. This product table has a one to many relationship with variation, one product can have multiple variations. The variation table also has a cod column.

```
  product     variation2      here product has two variations      
   cod 12       cod 13
   id 1         product_id 1
   user_id 100

         variation1
         cod 14
          product_id 1
```

The user cannot insert the product if he already inserted a product or variation with a specific code.

I need to validate this using laravel. I really don't want to use eloquent to to this. I with I could use Laravel validation.

The farthest I could get was:

```
  "cod" => 'unique:product|unique:variation'
```

But how can I base the validation by user_id on the product table?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of validation just make select for tables `product` `variation1` and `variation2` (with joins on 'cod') and if you will not get any row, then you can save model (still inside transaction). Because this situation is encapsulated to only one user (and I assume he can work from one computer at the same time) then you don't need to use [transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions) and [optymistic/pesymistic locking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34556511/860099)