# laravel get old records after lockForUpdate?

Tags: mysql, laravel

my code:

```html
DB::transaction(function () {
       $foo = Foo::whereId(1)->lockForUpdate()->with('bars')->first();
       // dump foo & bars
       // update foo's columns
       // update bars' columns
   });
```

and I run this code at the same time twice, first time it can update correctly, but the second time when I query the `foo`, `foo`'s columns is correct, but the `bars` are still old(in database it's correct), why is it and how to solve it?

Comment: I think you will have to reload the bar data too.Try $foo->fresh()->with('bars');

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `lockForUpdate()` and want to use the new data after you update, you need to re-hydrate the model using `refresh()`

> The refresh method will re-hydrate the existing model using fresh data from the database. In addition, all of its loaded relationships will be refreshed as well:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#refreshing-models

There is a great answer by NoOorZ24 @ [Laravel lockforupdate (Pessimistic Locking)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556511/laravel-lockforupdate-pessimistic-locking) explaining how the lock for transaction works to further clarify.